# Is it true that OpenCV can only do real time image processing on Android Studio?

Tags: opencv, android-studio, android

I am new to OpenCV and Android studio. I am creating a image processing android app. I would like to know if Opencv can do post processing on images, instead of only real time image processing in the camera view. Is there any examples on how to do post processing onto an image captured via the camera.

Comment: I don't think there's any particular limitation between Android Studio and OpenCV. Could you please share some material on that claim?

Comment: _I would like to know if Opencv can do post processing on images_ **Yes.** There's not much more that can be answered if you don't include further details

Comment: could you show me some examples or links to show how post processing is done with opencv?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do post-processing, there is no need to use Android at all unless it is a business requirement (and there is no need to use Android Studio which is the official IDE for Android).

Just use your computer and install [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), or install the [Medical Imaging Toolkit](http://docs.mitk.org/nightly/index.html). It will be much easier if you use your own computer instead of Android (although, the first link I gave you also has a version you can download for Android as well in case you really need to use that).

Comment: Hi sorry, i forgot to add i am developing an android app for image processing, thus i need to do it on android studio

Comment: @Sheng, First off, I would suggest you abandon the "android studio" requirement. It doesn't matter which IDE you choose to use. Both Eclipse and Android Studio can help you create OpenCV applications on Android. It's just that most tutorials you'll find will be using Eclipse (because until one year ago, it was a pain to use a C++ library with Android Studio). So just adapt the tutorials you do find to your Android Studio environment. As to code samples, I'd recommend the "15-puzzle" and the "image-manipulations" samples from http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html